# Reload ajax content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to load some content from a page into a simple lightbox.

It works great, however, with more than one link on a page with `class="ajax-page-content"`, clicking link A load Content A, but clicking link B loads Content A also.

How Do I ensure the correct content is loaded for each link?

Do I need to use `location.reload` or something to reload the content?

```
$('.ajax-page-content').click(function(){  

    var $button = $(this);
    var url = $button.attr('href');

    if ($('#addlee-lightbox-content').length > 0) {

        $('#addlee-lightbox-content').show();
        $('body').addClass('lightbox-open');
    } else {
        $.get(url, '', function (data) {

            var $content = $(data).find('.col');
            var html_content = $content.html();

            var lightbox =
            '<div id="lightboxcontent">' +
                '<div class="lightbox-content animated fadeInDown">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="lightbox-close">&nbsp;</a>' +
                    html_content +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="lightbox-bg">&nbsp;</div>' +
            '</div>';

            $('body').append(lightbox).addClass('lightbox-open');

        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What's the url in the links? Can you show your HTML?

Comment: It depends on your html structure - i.e. where elements and classes are placed.

Comment: This should work. Your code finds the link (`$button = $(this)`) and uses its href, so if each button has a different href, it should load different contents. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Is it the link with href="#" that always load "Content A" ? What should this link do when clicked ? Should it have the same href as the 'ajax-page-content' button ?

Comment: Sure the links look like this <a href="/terms/" class="ajax-page-content">Terms and Conditions</a>

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of your logic in script.
You write something like:

If container exist, show it
else, create container, populate it, show it

So, in your second click, the first condition executes.

Edit: an sketch of the logic should be like:

click link - fetch ajax data
populate container wth ajax data
show modal

An alteration is to use the click event to add (and populate) multiple containers to your page. Each container should hold the ajax data of a single click.
So something like:
click on LinkA, fetch dataA, populate containerA, open modalA
click on LinkB, fetch dataB, populate containerB, open modalB
click on LinkA, open modalA

Comment: I see, so how would I fix it?